# Require once / Include no Laravel

Tags: laravel, include, require

Estou tentando fazer o include de um arquivo em uma página num site feito em Laravel. O arquivo e a página estão em servidores diferentes. Como posso fazer isso?

Tentei com include e deu o seguinte erro : `include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0`

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o problema, por favor, considere marcá-la.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve alterar as configurações do seu PHP, no arquivo **php.ini**. Altere o valor de [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) para `1`.